# Highcharts: SeriesMapping with CSV

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart that works very well when using the data module with Google spreadsheets. However I need to stop using Google sheets and use CSV on my own server instead. Some of my charts are working, but some aren't. Here's one that is not working. It uses the second column to set the point color, but it's not recognizing it. Any idea what might be wrong here? I edited some of the csv entries to try to make it work, but it's not working much:

http://jsfiddle.net/jmunger/cf6L4bmk/20/

```
    var chart = Highcharts.chart('gfx', {

    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
    },
    data: {
        csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML,
        itemDelimiter: ',',
        seriesMapping: [{
            color: 2,
            label: 3
        }]
    }

});

console.log(chart);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That problem seems to be a bug in a data module, so I reported it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13283

As a workround you can use other color formats:

```
0;1;blue
1;2;rgb(155,155,55)
2;3;red
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0gjbn4m6/1/